# C# .ToString("X4") equivalent in Java

Tags: c#, java, string, unicode

While converting String to Unicode, I am looking for a **true equivalent of C# .ToString("X4") in Java.**

**C# Code:**

```
char[] stringChars = "Notices".ToCharArray();
List<string> ucs2code = new List<string>();
foreach (char chr in stringChars)
{
    string chrCode = ((int)chr).ToString("X4");
    ucs2code.Add(chrCode);
}
string charCode = string.Join("", ucs2code);
```

It gives me **`004E006F00740069006300650073`** as a result which is exactly what I need.

**Java code** that I tried

```
char[] stringChars = "Notices".toCharArray();
String charCode = "";
for (char chr : stringChars) {
    String chrCode = Integer.toHexString((int)chr);
    charCode += chrCode;
}
```

This gives me **`4e6f7469636573`** It looks correct but not quite what I need.

Is there anything I missed? some suggestions would help a lot.

Comment: isnt it just a matter of padding each `chrCode` with 00 and converting to upper case?

Comment: @thumbmunkeys: thanks, yes correct. Although, that would solve the problem but be called as workaround not a true equivalent of it. :-)

Comment: I would call it a solution :)

Comment: Indeed, it solves the problem, so why not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there isn't are true equivalent. 
Java has a `Format`-class, if you would like to take a look at that.

```
function:Integer.toHexString((int)chr)
```

Is here the correct way to do it, so that should be it.

Comment: Solution: either Formatting a String or just concatenating as "00" + String.toUpperCase() works the same.
Thanks

Comment: Alright, I am not really the Java-guy, but glad to see the problem solved. :)

Comment: Me neither, I have been redeveloping my previous tool in C#.Net to Java and came across several questions like this one. Quite obvious though :-)