# C# to C++ function equivelent - .tostring("X4")

Tags: c#, c++, string

Is there a functional equivalent for the C# function .tostring("X4"), to C++?

I've been scratching my head for a few days wondering why my sensor is reporting a different serial number to what the manufacturer software (written in C#) and what my C++ code reports. The serial number is also written on the sensor, which ties in with what the manufacturer C# code reports. On inspection of their source code, they're using the .tostring("X4") function to convert it to "human readable", which makes sense (from a "oh thats why it's different", not a "why on earth would you do that" point of view).

For further info - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings

A similar question but C# to Java - [C# .ToString("X4") equivalent in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23107029/c-sharp-tostringx4-equivalent-in-java)

Comment: Use sscanf or sprintf.

Comment: (For context, `X4` formats the number as upper-case hexadecimal digits, padding with leading 0's to a total of 4 characters if necessary)

Comment: If you can afford using 3rd party libs, you can try [fmt](https://fmt.dev/latest/syntax.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's is no readily available equivalent function in C++, but you could create one that works in a similar way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

template<class T>
std::string tostringX(unsigned len, T v) {
    std::ostringstream os;
    os << std::hex << v;
    auto rv = os.str();
    if(rv.size() < len) rv = std::string(len - rv.size(), '0') + rv;
    return rv;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << tostringX(4, 0xFEDC) << '\n'; // outputs "fedc"
}
```

Comment: That worked a treat thankyou so much! Sensor now reports the correct serial number.

Answer (score 2):

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include<sstream>
    #include <iomanip>
    
    int main() {
        int x = 12;
        std::stringstream stream;
        stream << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(4)<< std::hex << x;
        std::cout << stream.str();
    }
```

**Output** : 000c

I guess that's the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Using `setfill` and `setw` is nicer than what I did in my answer. +1 (although `sizeof(x)` for the width is a bit questionable - `sizeof(x)` could be 2 or even 8)

Comment: @TedLyngmo  thanks a lot.It may differ as you say yes :)